# Цикл while не выполняется

Tags: python

Цикл while не хочет выполняться.

Не могу понять почему, так как логическое выражение у меня вроде верно, я понимаю его так «пока 0 и 0 не равно 1 выполнить цикл:»

Ошибок не выдаёт

```
x =0
y=0
while x and y != 1:
    q = int(input("число введи: "))
    if q == 1:
        x += 1 
        print("x:", x)
    elif q == 2:
        y  += 1
        print("y:", y)
print("end")
```

Comment: while x - пока x True (или приводимое к true значение). 0 - это False

Comment: Если вы хотели написать "пока x == 0", то нужно было это писать в явном виде `while x == 0 and y != 1:`